# SQL Update single row, Where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am updating a *single row* by *unique index*:

```
UPDATE Users SET Enabled=1 WHERE Id=1
```

Does it make sense regarding to execution speed to check if it is already `Enabled` ?

```
UPDATE Users SET Enabled=1 WHERE Id=1 AND Enabled<>1
```

Comment: You will have to specify which RDBMs specifically, how they behave varies based on the database engine.

Comment: what indexes do you have defined? -- for example if you have an index defined on id but not on enabled then the 2nd way will be slower not faster.

Comment: Id is a unique index, Enabled is not (it can be either 0 or 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to write SQL scripts that are idempotent:

```
UPDATE Users 
SET Enabled=1 
WHERE Id=1 
  AND Enabled<>1;   -- if column is defined as NOT NULL
```

Scenarios:

- trigger that writes to shadow/history table (it will fire only once)
- last update date (will change only once)
- change tracking will not mark row as updated
- maybe slower but  more consistent

Comment: Additional clause can make the SQL slower? Not faster? Even assuming that in significant number (20%-80%) of cases the row is not updated. as I see there is no scenario to be my case, i just need to make sure that Enabled is 1 as fast as possible, nothing more.